# Mixed Integer Linear Program Infeasible Solution in Python PuLP

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I formulated a MILP to model a multi-period multi-customer scheduling problem in PuLP. The aim is to schedule multiple batches of products to be produced in a week such that all the product batches are manufactured by minimizing total cost of labor. Each day has a regular shift and an over-time shift(which is more expensive to use due to the variable cost of labor).

I've used two variables both that are created as 'Integer' variables. However, I still get decimal and negative values in my problem solution. How is this possible? Please see my code below.

```
'''
Multi-Period Scheduling Problem
'''
from pulp import *
import itertools
```

Creating the parameters and data:

```
'''SETS'''

#list of batch_id's waiting for production
batch_ids = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6']

#list of the days available in a week
days = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri']

#list of shifts in a day
shifts= ['rt', 'ot']

'''PARAMETERS'''

#batch quantity needed
batch_size= {    
            'b1': 45,
            'b2': 60,
            'b3': 120,
            'b4': 80,
            'b5': 230,
            'b6': 40
        }

#regular time and over time values
time_dict= {'rt': 450, 'ot': 300}

#dict to store minutes available per day per shift
mins_per_day= {d: {s: time_dict[s] for s in shifts} for d in days}

#cycle time in minutes per unit per batch
cycle_time = {    
            'b1': 45,
            'b2': 30,
            'b3': 10,
            'b4': 80,
            'b5': 13,
            'b6': 35
        }

'''minimum needed units per batch per day; as of now this is a fixed   qty= 10, but we can create a separate
dict to store different qty per batch if needed and then use it in the    dict comprehension here'''
min_qty= {d:{b: 5 for b in batch_ids} for d in days}

pay_by_shift= {'ot': 0.8625, 'rt': 0.575}

#cost per minute per shift per day:
pay_dict= {d: {s: pay_by_shift[s] for s in shifts} for d in days}

#indexes for batch and day combinations
shifts_ind = [(d,s) for d in days for s in shifts]

#indexes for the make variable:
make_ind= [(d,b) for d in days for b in  batch_ids]
```

Defining the variables:

```
'''VARIABLES'''

#number of units of a batch scheduled for production per day per shift
make= LpVariable.dicts("Make Per Day",(days, batch_ids, shifts),0, None,     cat= 'Integer')

#binary variable to decide wether OT is scheduled on a given day or not
y= LpVariable.dicts("Use Shift",(days, shifts), 0, 1, cat= 'Integer')

'''model formulation'''

#create model object with a minimize objective
prob= LpProblem("FlexLine Problem",LpMinimize)
```

Defining the Objective Function

```
#objective function
prob += lpSum([y[d][s] for d in days for s in shifts]) + \
        lpSum([make[d][b][s]* cycle_time[b]* pay_dict[d][s] for d in    days for b in batch_ids for s in shifts]), "Total labor cost per week"
```

Defining the constraints:

```
'''CONSTRAINTS'''

#demand constraint
for b in batch_ids:
    prob += lpSum([make[d][b][s] for d in days for s in shifts]) ==     batch_size[b] 

#time constraint
for (d,s) in shifts_ind:
prob += lpSum([make[d][b][s] * cycle_time[b] for b in batch_ids]) <=    mins_per_day[d][s] * y[d][s]

#minimum per day constraint
for (d,b) in make_ind:
    prob += lpSum([make[d][b][s] for s in shifts]) >= min_qty[d][b]

#linking constraint
for (d,s) in shifts_ind:
    prob += lpSum([make[d][b][s] for b in batch_ids]) <= 100000 * y[d][s]
```

Solving the model:

```
prob.solve()
Out: -1

print ("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])
Out: Status: Infeasible
```

Printing the variable values:

```
for v in prob.variables():
print (v.name, "=", v.varValue)

Out:Make_Per_Day_fri_b1_ot = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_fri_b1_rt = 5.0
Make_Per_Day_fri_b2_ot = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_fri_b2_rt = -5.5
Make_Per_Day_fri_b3_ot = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_fri_b3_rt = 5.0
Make_Per_Day_fri_b4_ot = 1.5625
Make_Per_Day_fri_b4_rt = 3.4375
Make_Per_Day_fri_b5_ot = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_fri_b5_rt = 5.0    
Make_Per_Day_fri_b6_ot = 5.0
Make_Per_Day_fri_b6_rt = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_mon_b1_ot = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_mon_b1_rt = 5.0
Make_Per_Day_mon_b2_ot = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_mon_b2_rt = -5.5
Make_Per_Day_mon_b3_ot = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_mon_b3_rt = 5.0
Make_Per_Day_mon_b4_ot = 2.9375
Make_Per_Day_mon_b4_rt = 2.0625
Make_Per_Day_mon_b5_ot = 5.0
Make_Per_Day_mon_b5_rt = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_mon_b6_ot = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_mon_b6_rt = 5.0
Make_Per_Day_thu_b1_ot = 25.0
Make_Per_Day_thu_b1_rt = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_thu_b2_ot = 61.0
Make_Per_Day_thu_b2_rt = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_thu_b3_ot = 131.5
Make_Per_Day_thu_b3_rt = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_thu_b4_ot = 60.0
Make_Per_Day_thu_b4_rt = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_thu_b5_ot = 210.0
Make_Per_Day_thu_b5_rt = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_thu_b6_ot = 16.142857
Make_Per_Day_thu_b6_rt = 12.857143
Make_Per_Day_tue_b1_ot = 5.0
Make_Per_Day_tue_b1_rt = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_tue_b2_ot = 0.83333333
Make_Per_Day_tue_b2_rt = 4.1666667
Make_Per_Day_tue_b3_ot = 5.0
Make_Per_Day_tue_b3_rt = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_tue_b4_ot = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_tue_b4_rt = 5.0
Make_Per_Day_tue_b5_ot = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_tue_b5_rt = 5.0
Make_Per_Day_tue_b6_ot = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_tue_b6_rt = -4.0
Make_Per_Day_wed_b1_ot = 5.0
Make_Per_Day_wed_b1_rt = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_wed_b2_ot = 5.0
Make_Per_Day_wed_b2_rt = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_wed_b3_ot = -26.5
Make_Per_Day_wed_b3_rt = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_wed_b4_ot = 1.5625
Make_Per_Day_wed_b4_rt = 3.4375
Make_Per_Day_wed_b5_ot = 5.0
Make_Per_Day_wed_b5_rt = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_wed_b6_ot = 0.0
Make_Per_Day_wed_b6_rt = 5.0
Use_Shift_fri_ot = 1.0
Use_Shift_fri_rt = 1.0
Use_Shift_mon_ot = 1.0
Use_Shift_mon_rt = 1.0
Use_Shift_thu_ot = 41.216667
Use_Shift_thu_rt = 1.0
Use_Shift_tue_ot = 1.0
Use_Shift_tue_rt = 1.0
Use_Shift_wed_ot = 1.0
Use_Shift_wed_rt = 1.0
```

To reiterate, I am seeing negative values, decimals as well as binary variables showing up as more than 1. How is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution status is not feasible or optimal (It seems infeasible). Therefore variable values doesn't mean anything. You can decrease batch sizes and try to find feasible solution and working model. Also using "writeLP" you can examine your model with numbers.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to find an optimal solution by reducing the batch sizes! And the 'writeLP' method was really really useful....I'm going to fine tune the model further.